# HTML Label tag adds whitespace above element when it contains content

Tags: html, css

I have a list of form elements. Labels go next to each element. Some labels, some have text. They are behaving differently in different browsers.

Essentially what's happening is that the labels which have text are creating whitespace above the list items. The form is much more complex than this, but I've boiled it down to this basic code: http://jsfiddle.net/uZ2Et/

```
#cleanVersion li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#cleanVersion label {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 70px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
​

<div id="cleanVersion">
    <ul>
        <li><label>test</label></li>
        <li><label></label></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

I've tried adjusting the margins, borders, padding, line-height... but still the labels remain inconsistent.

How do I get rid of the whitespace which appears above the list items with text in them?

Edit: Here's a more complex example which is closer to what I'm actually doing: http://jsfiddle.net/uZ2Et/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top;` on the list items: http://jsfiddle.net/uZ2Et/1/

Comment: In my simplified version, that works. In the version I'm trying to make work, it doesn't. Give this one a try http://jsfiddle.net/uZ2Et/6/

Comment: Put it on the list items' children then: `.refine-search-container li > * { vertical-align: top; }` http://jsfiddle.net/uZ2Et/9/

Comment: Ok, so I have to add `vertical-align: top;` to each element - label, select, input - and then they all align the same. Previously I had everything vertical aligned middle, which is the look I was going for, but then I had this issue and it wasn't consistent across browsers. At least now they're all on the top and moving them down should be the same across all browsers. Thanks for helping me think to investigate that some more.